# retrieve data from api

Tags: php, json, api

I am Passing  array of parameter to api and Trying to return  same Array Elements in json format

I have created very simple 2 pages

1.
 For sending array with api

```
<?php
$array['Phone'] =  123456;
$array['name'] = 'name1';
$array['email'] = 'testemail';
$array['password'] = 'password';
$array['api_key'] = $api_key;
$array['referral_code'] = 'kk';

$url = "http://getsjobs.esy.es/registerapi.php?Array[]=$array";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
if(!$json) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($json,true);


foreach ($data as $item) {

    echo $data;

}
?>php
```

and

2. Trying to return the same array as JSON Format (For testing )

   ```
   <?PHP

   if(isset($_GET['Array[]'])) {

   $_Phone= $array['Phone'];
   $_name = $array['name'];
   $_email = $array['email'];
   $_password = $array['password'];
   $api_key = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
   $_referral_code = $array['referral_code'];


   $posts = $_GET['Array[]'];

   header('Content-type: application/json');


   }


   ?>
   ```

But SomeHow Json data is not able to fetch array from api .I have Tried to create the code carefully by following examples from here , Still I think something is missing here .

just need one Hint what could be reason that array is not passing or recieving ?Any help would be apprecited

Comment: pass it as a query string as a field <-> value pairs

Comment: can you please suggest one code example ?

Answer (score 0):

The way you pass data is incorrect, PHP probably will throw an Array to String conversion error on this line

```
$url = "http://getsjobs.esy.es/registerapi.php?Array[]=$array";
```

You need to do it like this

```
<?php
$api_key = '';

$params = [
    'Array[Phone]' => 123456,
    'Array[name]' => 'name1',
    'Array[email]' => 'testemail',
    'Array[password]' => 'password',
    'Array[api_key]' => $api_key,
    'Array[referral_code]' => 'kk',
];
$url = "http://localhost/test.php?".http_build_query($params);

// echo $url;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
if(!$json) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($json,true);

foreach ($data as $item) {

    echo $item."<br/>\n";

}
```

To retrieve data:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['Array'])) {
    $array = $_GET['Array'];

    $_Phone= $array['Phone'];
    $_name = $array['name'];
    $_email = $array['email'];
    $_password = $array['password'];
    $api_key = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    $_referral_code = $array['referral_code'];

    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

Comment: How do i retrieve the value from $params from another page

Comment: Edited my answer. It's the working code I set up to test this.

Comment: can you come to chat .... it is still not working .. "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() "

Comment: That's probably because you echoed `$data` instead of `$item`